# Why am I getting wrong answer for this simple calculation

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I am trying to write a code which does this simple calculation in python

[image]

My code:

```
T0 = 1.0

def T_iteration(n):
    def Ti(i):
        if i<=0:
            return T0
        else:
            return Ti(i-1)+(1.0/n)*((-2*Ti(i-1)) + (0.5*math.exp(-((i-1)/n))))
    T_list = []
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        T_list.append(Ti(i))
    return T_list
```

Output:

```
T_iteration(3)
Out[292]: [1.0, 0.5, 0.33333333333333337, 0.2777777777777778]
```

Why is my output different to the example in the question? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just guessing it's a type error. Check the final `math.exp` parameter. That's doing integer arithmetic, right? You probably want it to be doing floating point, so that `1 / 3` returns 0.3333... not 0. `(i-1)*1.0/n` might do the trick.

Comment: Thats it. Thanks Jonathan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that there's integer division towards the end of your expression.

```
return Ti(i-1)+(1.0/n)*((-2*Ti(i-1)) + (0.5*math.exp(-((i-1)/n))))
                                                            ^
                                                           HERE
```

You should either:

- Make that a decimal, or
- Import `division` from `__future__` instead, and remove the decimal from the earlier `1.0/n` for consistency's sake.

  ```
  from __future__ import division
  import math
  ```

Answer (score 2):

**(0.5*math.exp(-((i-1)/n)))** should be changed to **(0.5*math.exp(-((i-1.0)/n)))** since **(i-1)/n** would lose precision.